# How do I properly loop through all csv from a df list and present it in global environment without the full path name or extension end as df?

Tags: r, dataframe

after running filelist=lapply(filestoread,read.csv)

i do

```
names(filelist) <- gsub(directory,"",filestoread)
```

but i get my result as

```
df.csv,df2.csv,df3.csv
```

when i do this

```
names(filelist)<- gsub("\\.csv$", "", filestoread)
```

I get

"C://User//df","C://User//df2","C://User//df3"

I try doing this

```
names(filelist) <- gsub(directory & "\\.csv$", "", filestoread)
```

so i can get

```
df,df1,df2
```

Comment: I suggest you use the function `list.files()` which returns a character vector of filenames. Then your `gsub()` on the file ending will work to remove the `.csv` from that vector.

Comment: list.files(path = directory,pattern = "^df.*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

Comment: I did that already. I have everything prepared. its just the names are giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see whether I understand what you want to do or have done.
I make use of a sub-folder with Excel files ...

```
# retrieve list of files in subfolder
pth = "path-on-my-machine"

# only see what we have - this is an example on my computer
list.files(path = pth, pattern = "xlsx$")
[1] "spikes.xlsx"
[2] "normal.xlsx"       
[3] "test-remove-pivot.xlsx"  

# let's store the results in a variable                                        
filelist <- list.files(path = pth, pattern = "xlsx$")

# chack what we stored 
filelist

[1] "spikes.xlsx"
[2] "normal.xlsx"       
[3] "test-remove-pivot.xlsx"                                          
#------------------- that is the expected/wanted behaviour

# now I want to write names in my result vector
# check what names it has right now
names(filelist)
NULL
#------------------- obviously it is NULL as no names assigned


# how to substitute parts of the vector element (aka content)
gsub(pattern = ".xlsx$", replacement = "", filelist)
[1] "spikes" "normal" "test-remove-pivot"                                          

# OK - we can replace the ending


# Now ... let's name the vector elements
names(filelist) <- gsub(pattern = ".xlsx$", replacement = "", filelist)

filelist
   spikes 
"spikes.xlsx" 
   normal 
"normal.xlsx" 
   test-remove-pivot 
 "test-remove-pivot.xlsx" 
# ----------------- woohoo - we have a named vector with the filenames without file ending as names
```

Check whether you want to name your vector elements or change the elements (content).

Comment: The problem with mine is that in filelist you have spikes.xlsx, but i have "C://Users//Name//spikes.xlsx"

Comment: I see in list.files i had full.names=TRUE. Maybe that was my era. Checking now.

Comment: hhhhmmmm .... not sure where this comes from. The default for `list.files()` is actually `full.names = FALSE`. Thus the full names should not be extracted or listed. Try setting it deliberately.

Comment: lol ...you beat me by a few seconds. Well spotted. That is the culprit. sorry, i should have raised this first

Comment: Still helpful lay out. I appreciate it. Do you know the puprose of having it as full.names= FALSE?

Comment: As always with coding ... it depends on the use case. Obviously, if you share code and/or want to make your solution generic, it is a better approach to set the path rather than having it in your filename. On a more esotheric note ... the function is called `list.files()` and not `list.path.to.and.including.files()` ... so I guess the creator had some thoughts about this :)